# jquery UI draggability and resizability not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I had this draggability code working when I used external resources on jsfiddle.

But, by including the jquery and jquery ui files via script and style tags doesn't make my divs draggable and/or resizable.

This is so annoying. I have been trying this for so long.

[Here's my code](https://jsfiddle.net/akashdmukherjee/wj41wLcx/1/)

**HTML:**

```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <div id="outer" style="background-color: #3C3C3C; width: 300px; height: 300px;">
           <div id="object1" class="draggable resizable">
           </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
  .draggable.resizable
  {
      position: relative; 
      display: -moz-inline-stack;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
      zoom: 1;
      *display: inline;   

      cursor: hand; 
      cursor: pointer;
      border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
      z-index: 1;
  }


  .ui-resizable-handle  {
      background: #E0E0E0;
      width: 9px;
      height: 9px;
      z-index: 0;
  }


  .ui-resizable-se
  {
      right: -5px;
      bottom: -5px;
  }

  .ui-resizable-ne
  {
      right: -5px;
      bottom: -5px;
  }



  #object1 {
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 20px;
    width:30px;
    height: 50px;

  }
```

**JS:**

```
  $('.draggable').draggable({
    containment: '#outer'
  });

  $('.resizable').resizable({
      //aspectRatio: true,
        containment:'#outer'
      , handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw'
  });
```

Comment: Change all your source files' path from `http://` to `//`. Notice that you are under `https://`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As user R Lam pointed out, if you open the console in your web browser you should see the following errors.

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/akashdmukherjee/wj41wLcx/1/show/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
>   (index):117 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/akashdmukherjee/wj41wLcx/1/show/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
>   (index):1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/akashdmukherjee/wj41wLcx/1/show/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
>   (index):97 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

It can be fixed by replacing http:// to //

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

[The following JS Fiddle works](https://jsfiddle.net/z57srn9p/)